# Matrix multiplication seen as derivative or integral

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, integration, derivatives

I'm reading the book "Introduction to Linear Algebra 5th edition" page 24 about Inverse Matrix, below is the background info.

$$ \mathbf{A} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ -1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}, \qquad
\mathbf{x} = \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \end{bmatrix}, \qquad
\mathbf{b} = \begin{bmatrix} b_1 \\ b_2 \\ b_3 \end{bmatrix}.
$$

In which the author mentioned
"The differences $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}$ become the derivative $\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t} = b(t)$. In the inverse direction, the sums $\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{b}$ become the integral of $b(t)$."

I'm so confused about these statements, I'm thinking he meant vector $\mathbf{x}$ as a function, which applied to matrix $\mathbf{A}$, so $\mathbf{x}(t)$ is the $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}$.  Then how could: "$\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}$ become the derivative $\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t} = b(t)$"? As I cant imagine the derivative of $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}$ or $x(t)$ here.

$$ \mathbf{A}\mathbf{x} = \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 - x_1 \\ x_3 - x_2 \end{bmatrix} $$

---

[image: book page]

Comment: He's probably linking linear systems of equations and linear system of differential equations (with constant coefficients). You'll obtain similar formulas in both cases.

Comment: I think some context is needed. First of all, who is the author? The title isn't unique among all linear algebra textbooks. Secondly, what part of the text are you reading? From the two paragraphs you've clipped, it looks like an introduction. There's more detail than a normal introduction, but less than in the main text.

Comment: "Introduction to Linear Algebra-5th edition-2016" by Gilbert Strang,  thank you

Comment: Please use MathJax to format your question. It greatly helps the question visible to various search engines and hence is crucial for maintaining this community as a repository of mathematical knowledge. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Sorry, I'll learn how to use that

Answer (score 3):

Imagine the following situation: We want to record a signal, which is given by a function $f(t)$ of time. Due do the limitation of the recording device, however, we can only able to sample the values of $f$ every $\Delta t$ unit of times. If the recording has started at time $t = 0$, the resulting time series will be given by a vector

$$ \mathbf{x} = \begin{bmatrix}
x_0 \\
x_1 \\
x_2 \\
\vdots
\end{bmatrix},
\qquad\text{where}\qquad
t_k = k \Delta t \quad\text{ and } x_k = f(t_k). $$

Now suppose we are interested in computing (or approximating) the derivative of $f$ using the data $\mathbf{x}$. For simplicity, we also assume that $f(t) = 0$ for $t < 0$. Assuming $\Delta t$ is small, the derivative of $f(t)$ at time $t_k$ can be approximated as follows:

$$ f'(t_k) \approx \frac{f(t_{k}) - f(t_{k-1})}{t_{k} - t_{k-1}}
= \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{\Delta t}(x_k - x_{k-1}), & k \geq 1, \\
\frac{1}{\Delta t}x_0, & k = 0.
\end{cases} $$

Consequently, we have

$$ \frac{1}{\Delta t} \underbrace{ \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots \\
-1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots \\
0 & -1 & 1 & 0 & \cdots \\
0 & 0 & -1 & 1 & \cdots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots
\end{bmatrix} }_{\mathbf{A}} \mathbf{x}
\approx
\begin{bmatrix}
f'(t_0) \\ f'(t_1) \\ f'(t_2) \\ f'(t_3) \\ \vdots
\end{bmatrix}. $$

So the matrix $\mathbf{A}$ behaves like a scaled version of the differential operator $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}$.

Comment: Thank you Lee, the above text greatly helped me understand the use case and background of matrix transformation applied on a vector and how it can be thought of as a "taking derivative" of vector.

Previously, I was wondering if we can take a matrix or vector as a function or input, then there is a systemic way of taking the derivative of such a function. 

P.S. Should I read calculus before start linear algebra?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things which help anyone learning linear algebra from Gil Strang's texts:

1. Strang writes in a pretty conversational style, and fills in details after motivating the ideas.
2. Strang's lectures are online and form a good companion to the text.

One remark which might add some context to the portion you clipped comes on page 27:

> This section is looking ahead to key ideas, not fully explained yet.

*What I think* Strang is saying here with “The differences $Ax$ become the derivative $dx/dt$...” etc., is that

- Differential equations $x'(t) = b(t)$ are an infinite-dimensional version of linear equations $Ax=b$.
- If a vector is treated like a time series, the difference matrix $A$ has a lot of the same features of a derivative operator on differentiable functions, and the sum matrix $A^{-1}$ as a lot of the same features as an integration operator.

Comment: Thank you Matthew, the page 27 context gives me some confidence to continue.

Answer (score 0):

The system of equation

$$
AX=\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
-1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 1
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{l}
\mathbf{x_1} \\
\mathbf{x_2} \\
\mathbf{x_3}
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{l}
\mathbf{1} \\
\mathbf{1} \\
\mathbf{1}
\end{array}\right] = b
$$

is similar to the system of differential equations

\begin{equation}
    \begin{cases}
      \frac{dx_1}{dt} = x_1(t) & \\
      \frac{dx_2}{dt} = -x_1(t) + x_2(t) \\
       \frac{dx_3}{dt} = -x_2(t)+x_3(t)
    \end{cases}       
\end{equation}

as it can be written $AX(t)=\frac{dX}{dt}$ where $X(t) = \begin{pmatrix} x_1(t) \\ x_2(t) \\ x_3(t) \end{pmatrix}$ and  $\frac{dX}{dt} = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{dx_1(t)}{dt} \\ \frac{dx_2(t)}{dt} \\ \frac{dx_3(t)}{dt} \end{pmatrix}$. The functions $x_1, x_2, x_3$ are real (1D) functions.

The two equations are formally the same if you replace $b$ by $\frac{dX}{dt}$ and the vector $x$ by a vector function $X(t)$. Also, you get that applying $A$ to $X(t)$ is equivalent to differentiation giving  $\frac{dX}{dt}$  and on the opposite, if you apply $A^{-1}$ to  $\frac{dX}{dt}$ you get $X(t)$ which means an integration.

All this may seem confusing. There is not necessarily a deep reason just an analogy that can be made between the two cases. The connection between the two problems just comes from the property of linearity.

Comment: I know that A*x can be rewritten as a form of x_1 * (1, -1, 0) + x_2 * (0, 1, -1) + x_3 * (0, 0, 1).  Whereas why d(x_1)/dt = x_1(t) in above curved parentheses?  Don't we start from the x(t) as a function and then take the derivative of it?

Comment: The first row is just a $1$ in first position so only $x_1(t)$ is involved.